# Internal Hard Drive Mounting As Read Only?

Tags: dual-boot, mount

My computer has a 525GB SSD and a 2TB Western Digital HDD. I have a 147GB partition running Windows 10 and a 367GB partition running Ubuntu 16.10. The SSD is running completely fine, but the 2TB drive sometimes mounts as Read Only. This seems to only happen when I have previously booted into Windows. Restarting into Ubuntu, no matter how many times I do it, does not fix the issue. If I reboot into Windows, however, and then back into Ubuntu, the issue resolves itself. This is not an ideal fix, and I would like a way to have the drive mount properly. I should also note that I have to click on the drive from the Unity task bar in order to mount it, as it does not automatically do so on login.

I've read a few things online (though they were just for general troubleshooting of a drive mounting as read only) and the general consensus is to either run chown or to try remounting. However neither of these solutions have worked for me. I've tried a few other miscellaneous things to try and fix the drive but nothing has worked.

EDIT: The WD HDD is formatted to NTFS. It has no partitions on it either.

Comment: The WD drive is formatted how? Can you show `lsblk`? Also, what messages do you get when you try to remount the WD drive read-write?

Comment: Make sure your _unmounting the device properly and completely_ after each use especially on windows.

Comment: @AlexP Whoops, apologies. I'll edit my original post after I make this comment. The WD drive is formatted to NTFS.

Comment: @George The drive is internal so I shouldn't have to unmount it when I switch the machine off, should I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that it is an issue with Windows, that Windows is sometimes leaving the drive in a state, that is not good. I suspect that Windows is hibernating or using fast startup which is a kind of semi-hibernating, when you shut it down. But when you reboot Windows, it is *not* doing any of that, and the file systems are clean.

I suggest that you check if this is the problem, and if it is, do not use hibernation, and/or turn off fast startup in Windows. You can find several links to tutorials how to turn it off, for example this one:

[www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4189-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-10-a.html](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4189-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-10-a.html)

Comment: I will follow your suggestion on disabling hibernation and fast startup. Is there any kind of way I can check (from Linux) if this is actually the case? I mean I'm sure there's no harm in disabling it but I'd like to check to see if the drive is being left in _any_ kind of state. Thanks for the reply, and I'll test this as soon as I possibly can.

Comment: Maybe this behaviour, that Ubuntu is suffering from ;-) I suggest that you check in Windows according to the link in my previous comment

Answer (score 0):

My problem was solved very simple. I have Ubuntu and Windows on my pc. One day in Ubuntu a partition appeared as "read only" and none of the above solutions worked. I solved it by restarting, entering windows and going back to ubuntu. It worked more than once.

Comment: sounds like your issue was also related to hibernation or fast startup in Windows